# jQuery - execute function before default event

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I am using `jQTouch` (with `jQuery` and `Phonegap`) in my mobile app.

I want to ask user to verify himself by entering  the correct `passcode`.
Now the animations are working just fine when I `click` on the `anchor tags`...

But when I prompt for the `passcode`, a `div` is made visible to the user and he's supposed to enter his `passcode` there.

Now the problem is,

When he enters the `passcode`, I want to verify if the `passcode` is correct. If not I am showing an error message (which is working fine),
But how to first verify the passcode and then  have the `popped up box` `dissolve` or `fade` ? (I don't want slide animation here)

What I've tried is,

I have written the a function and in that function, if the passcode is correct, it is redirected to appropriate div using

`window.location.href = "#mydiv";`

But it works with sliding animation, I want fade or dissolve animation.

How to go about it?

OR

Is there any way I can execute the `function` before the actual `href` changes happen?

MORE CODE

```
function iconClick(e,that){
    if(localAppConfig.pinRequirement.wallet==1){
        $(that).addClass('dissolve');
        $(that).attr("href",'#p2p_login');
        $("#p2p_login a").attr("href","#content_nav");
    } else {
        $(that).removeClass('pop');
        window.location.href = "#content_nav";
    }
}
```

This is the function where I set the targets for my next animation.

`#p2p_login` is the pop up div, that I want to accept passcode in.
There is a button in `#p2p_login`, clicking on which the following function gets called.

```
function verifyPasscode(){
    var correctCode = localAppSecurity.passcode;
    var target = $("#p2p_login a").attr('href');
    var code = $("#p2p_login .txtfldPin").val();
    if(code==correctCode){
        $("#p2p_login a").addClass('fade');
        $("#p2p_login a").attr("href",target);
        $("#p2p_login .txtfldPin").css('border','3px solid #B9D973');
        window.location.href = target; // This triggers slide animation.. How to change it?

    } else {
        $("#p2p_login .txtfldPin").css('border','3px solid red');
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show more of your code.

Comment: Is using a timeout on the window.location.href and have the effect run before the href change possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.something').fadeOut(500, function(){
    //function to execute after animation completes
    window.location.href = "http://google.com";
});
```